# Templates vs. Action Hierarchy

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating a button class and am having a hard time deciding between 2 solutions.

1) Templatize the `Button` class and have it take a function object in its constructor to call when the button is pressed. The guy I'm coding with is worried that this will lead to code bloat/thrashing.

2) Create a ButtonAction base class, and there will be a different ButtonAction for each button. Thus the `Button` class takes a ButtonAction in its constructor to call when the button is pressed.

We've also considered the use of function pointers, but haven't thought it through that thoroughly.

Comment: Both are acceptable solutions.  What kind of criteria are you concerned about?  The second form might be a little more readable but definitely more wordy.  You can achieve the first solution without templates I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `boost::function<>` objects for your actions. This way you don't need any templates and the button class becomes very flexible:

```
struct Button {
   typedef boost::function<void ()> action_t;
   action_t action;

   Button(const action_t &a_action) : action(a_action) {
   }

   void click() {
      action();
   }
};
```

This way the class is easy to use with function pointers, functor objects or things like [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind):

```
void dosomething();
Button b1 = Button(&dosomething);

struct SomeAction {
   void operator()() {}
};
Button b2 = Button(SomeAction());
```

Comment: +1, also consider that in many frameworks you can connect more than one action to a single button. If you want to provide that functionality at one point or another, you just need to change your internal type to `boost::signal<void ()>` and call `.connect` instead of assigning the action to the `boost::function<>` object

Answer (score 1):

I'd enumerate the consequences of each alternative, and then decide which option is best for the particular case at hand.

If the template option might (premature worry?) bloat object code, then the polymorphism alternative might make the source code unnecessarily complex.

In the case of templates the compiler will create another `Button` class for each function object you instantiate it with. This means the product object code will be larger than if you have a single `Button` class that accepts various action objects through a subclass.

In the case of polymorphism the compiler will generate a single `Button` class but you will now have another base class to maintain, and you will be forced to subclass it for any new action you add to your collection. In particular you will not be able to use actions that were written before you created the base action class unless you can modify them so they derive from that action class.

The template alternative allows you to use anything at all that conforms to the template's interface. So if you use the template parameter as a function then you can accept anything at all that can be called like a function. This implies you don't even need to consider the alternative of function pointers, since templates allow you to accept function pointers -- and much more.

The polymorphism option implies the compiler knows more about what you're trying to do. In other words, templates come with templates errors.

You can ease some of the template issues if you can find a way to only template `Button` member-functions, rather than the entire `Button` class. Take as function parameter an instance of the template so you don't need to explicitly instantiate the template function. Then you win both on some of the template benefits as well as some of the polymorphism benefits.